# How to put parts of .bss segment in different RAM location with linker script?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-scripts

I am using an STM32H730VBHx and GCC toolchain with Cpp code. I have recently increased my code size resulting in the .bss section no longer fitting into DTCMRAM. Therefore I want to move some of the .bss and .COMMON section into my RAM_D1.

This has worked fine with with following linker script
[working script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkSFd.png)

---

However, as soon as I try to move other .bss sections like the ones in my files under CANOpen things do not work as expected.
[not working script part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5XgD.png)

---

With this liker script I get symbols that should now be in RAM_D1 still in DTCMRAM and other symbols that should remain in DTCMRAM now in RAM_D1.

For example ioHandler now moves to RAM_D1 even thought it is not in the CANOpen folder while canOpen is remains in DTCMRAM but should move:
[wrong location of symbol (singleton class)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WuyV.png)

The definition of canOpen in `canOpen.hpp` (singleton class):

```
    /**
 * @brief gets the Instance of this singleton class
 * @return reference to the object
 *
 */
static CANopen& getInstance(){
    static CANopen canOpen;

    return canOpen;

}
```

The definition of ioHandler in `IoDirect.hpp` (singleton class):

```
    /**
 * @brief gets the Instance of this singleton class
 * @return reference to the object
 */
static IoHandler& getInstance(){
    static IoHandler ioHandler;
    return ioHandler;
}
```

What could a possible reason for that be? It might also have to do with the newly introduced '    **bss_start** = _sbss_heap_D1RAM; ' ?

Comment: Are you *sure* ioHandler isn't in the CANOpen folder? Looks like an inline definition in the class, probably in the header file. Header files don't get linked. They get literally copy-pasted into every source file that includes them. So every source file that includes this header is going to define ioHandler, with a note to the linker saying "I know this is in every source file, just pick one at random"

Comment: Yes the ioHandler and canOpen instantiation is defined in the respective header files (see edited post). So you think it's random in which folder the symbols are or defined by the order of compilation? The strange thing is though that the symbol bT_Handler is defined similarly to be in D1_RAM and is working fine

Comment: I'd treat it as unpredictable